# jQuery .focus() doesn't work for the textarea

Tags: javascript

I want to focus on the textarea using jquery, so I wrote this:

```
let item = $('[data-model-abs-id="_player.5p6G3xVhKxa.6pN08IGqVGe.6dzqtCIQ2y4.6dkh6UeayIM"]');
item.focus();
```

It didn't work, so I tested if the textarea is selected or not:

```
let item = $('[data-model-abs-id="_player.5p6G3xVhKxa.6pN08IGqVGe.6dzqtCIQ2y4.6dkh6UeayIM"]');
item.animate({'top': '-=50px'},'slow');
```

The text input moves, so I think I selected the textarea correctly and at the right point.

I tested `item.get(0).focus();` and `setTimeout` and `setInterval` to initiate the focus but none of them worked.

Here is the last thing I tested (I'm using Chrome):

```
let interval = setInterval(focusEachSecond, 1000); // also setTimeout doesn't work

function focusEachSecond(){
  var item = $('[data-model-abs-id="_player.5p6G3xVhKxa.6pN08IGqVGe.6dzqtCIQ2y4.6dkh6UeayIM"]')
  item.focus()
}
```

Here is textarea tag:

```
<textarea style="font-family: &quot;Calibri Light Charset0_87E9C737&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 26.9764px; line-height: normal; font-weight: normal; direction: ltr; text-align: left; color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding: 1.47144px 2.4524px 0px; height: 34.3146px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);" maxlength="" data-accepts="events" placeholder="" data-reactid=".0.0.3.2.0.1.0:$_player=15p6G3xVhKxa=16pN08IGqVGe.0.3:$c803.1:$c993.$slideobject1275.2.0"></textarea>
```

What I'm missing and How to fix this?

Comment: Are you able to get the node in the variable `item`?

Comment: Are you sure `item` is not null? Have you checked in console `item.length`?

Comment: I get this when I log item : `init [div.slide-object.slide-object-textinput.shown., prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: "[data-model-abs-id="_player.5p6G3xVhKxa.6pN08IGqVGe.6dzqtCIQ2y4.6dkh6UeayIM"]"]`

Comment: `console.log(item.length)` returns `1`

Comment: It seems like a bug..

Comment: I loged the div class `console.log(item.prop('slide-object slide-object-textinput shown') ` and it returns `undefined`

Comment: What does `console.log(item.prop('tagName'))` returns in console? div?

Answer (score 1):

[**`.get()`**](https://api.jquery.com/get/) returns an array of raw DOM elements. [**`.eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) returns it as a jQuery object, meaning the DOM element is wrapped in the jQuery wrapper.

Try using [**`.eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```
item.eq(0).focus();
```

**Demo:**

```js
//$("li").get(0).addClass('myClass1');//Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).addClass is not a function
$("li").eq(1).addClass('myClass2');
```

```css
.myClass1{
  color: red;
}
.myClass2{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="foo">foo</li>
  <li id="bar">bar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @SaraRee, you may still have some issue in your code but the point I have mentioned is also valid, please check the code example...

Comment: `var item = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];

let userInputCheckPoints = setInterval(checkUserInput, 1000);

function checkUserInput(){      
     item.focus();
}`

Comment: I used the above code and it works fine but I don't know why?

Comment: @SaraRee, there is no such attribute (`data-model-abs-id`) in the element (textarea)!!!